# Does anyone have any performance metrics of ADO.NET connection pooling vs. the create-and-destroy method?

Tags: sql-server, performance, ado.net, connection-pooling

I'm using WCF, SQL Server and ADO.NET. I'm looking at two implementation options for the data access layer.

1. The Enterprise Library that uses connection pooling
2. A custom solution that does not use connection pooling. Every time the database is accessed a connection is created, used and then destroyed.

Option 2 looks like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)){...}
```

What is the difference in performance between these two? When does it make sense to pool connections?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 will have connection pooling as well unless you explicitly turn it off in the connection string.  Pooling is provided at the provider level and marking a connection "closed" just tells the pool to reuse it.  So there should be almost 0 perf difference between your 2 options.

Always.

Comment: Connection pooling can be turned off in the connection string and in that case option 2 will not use pooling and will create a new socket connection for every new database connection.

Comment: Good point.  Is there a case where you would ever want to do that?